# The playback of a .wmv video is balky on SharePoint Online; it stops and starts. Can I fix it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, wmv

To discover all my options for playing a .wmv video on my SharePoint Online site,. I configured 1) a Hero web part, 2) a Quick Links web part set up in several different ways, and 3) a File-Viewer web part. It obviously doesn't matter which web part I use, because in ALL cases, the video stops and starts during playback. The actual .wmv is stored in the Site Assets folder for the page on which the web parts are configured.

1. Do others have this problem?
2. What can I do to fix it?
3. Should I be using a different video format like MOV or AVI or something else?
4. Should I have stored the .wmv somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Per my test, I could not reproduce your issue.
2. Since videos stored in Microsoft 365 are based on Microsoft Stream service, and while Stream supports many formats, not all of them are accessible (for example: .wmv). **For the most accessible video, use the .mp4 format**.
3. No need to store video files to somewhere else.